# Aggregate strings using fuzzy matching

Tags: similarity, fuzzy-comparison

Suppose I have an error log and I wish to get a count of each *type* of error. I have already performed a naive count by grouping by error message, however a lot of the messages contain context-specific information, which means that despite being caused by the same bug I cannot simply group by message text.

Some examples, where the italicised segments vary per instance of error:

- failed to retrieve results for user *188a9e12-6797-4d9b-8adf-4588b2435326* on page */primate/gorilla*
- failed to retrieve results for user *08c610d2-27d2-4f97-bf60-d5b3010e8dd6* on page */primate/monkey*

I would like to group all such messages using some fuzzy logic. I understand the Levenshtein Distance algorithm is valuable for this type of processing, but I guess the raw distance is not valuable because it is not weighted against the string's length (a distance of 30 is less significant in a string of 1000 characters, versus 30 out of 100).

So my aim is to iterate over a list of messages and get some kind of fuzzily matched count. There may be a side issue of generating some kind of consistent key for each fuzzily matched message? How would i go about this?

Comment: Can't you use regular expressions to categorize your messages and capture the non varying part?

Comment: Unfortunately not, without mapping out regex for type of message. for each type of message different parts may vary, hence the need for fuzzy matching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would give [q-gram distance](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/) *a try*. The distance between two strings is then determined by the number of [N-grams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) they have in common. N would have to be large enough that an N-gram represents a relevant detail. N=4 might be a good starter.

Further string distances are derived from the concept of N-grams: f.x. cosine and Jaccard distance.

[This text](http://www.joyofdata.de/blog/comparison-of-string-distance-algorithms/) explains different types of string distance algorithms in context of R.

Comment: I'd forgotten I'd asked this question, and I can't remember exactly what I was trying to do! Your answer seems knowledgable and has plenty of useful links so I'll mark it as the answer